# How to Compile Openssl for linux-mips32 on a windows machine?

Tags: c, linux, openssl, wind-river-workbench

I have been struggling to build openssl for linux-mips32 using  VS2015x native Tools.
I have set up perl and use the following command to configure:

```
perl Configure linux-mips32
    --prefix=C:\Users\srivaspr\Downloads\openssl-1.0.2k.tar\openssl\builder 
    --openssldir=C:\Users\srivaspr\Downloads\openssl-1.0.2k.tar\openssl\builder
```

The configuration command works fine.

But when I use make command it gives the following error:

```
making all in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/srivaspr/Downloads/openssl-1.0.2k.tar/openssl/crypto'
gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -mips2 -mabi=32 -O3 -Wall -DBN_DIV3W -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DAES_ASM   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mabi=32'
gcc: note: valid arguments to '-mabi=' are: ms sysv
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mips2'
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: cryptlib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/srivaspr/Downloads/openssl-1.0.2k.tar/openssl/crypto'
make: *** [Makefile:287: build_crypto] Error 1
```

I have searched through the internet multiple times but could not find anything relevant. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest : Use a "linux mips" package, examples https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.1 → `$ file libssl.so.1.1` replies `libssl.so.1.1: ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked`

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am really new to this?

Comment: openssl-1.0.2k : 26 Jan 2017. ... Must it be version `1.0.2k` ? The version closest to k is 1.0.2u https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.0.2 : {`libssl1.0.2, libssl1.0-dev`}  .... Elaborate : Either install package(s) as is, or unpack .. and use the files.

Comment: Okay, so I have the files. But these are binary files. Aren't these suppose to be created after compilation? Also, One thing that I have observed is, everytime I build it for some OS, an opensslconf-{OS info}.h file in created. Eg: opensslconf-i386 for Cent OS. My objective is to get the same OS specific file for WIndRiverLinux5

Comment: No "opensslconf-[arch]" in CentOS 6 or 7 : `$ locate opensslconf` .... There is an old (2012) man page opensslconf https://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html , and there is `/usr/include/openssl/opensslconf-x86_64.h` ... No opensslconf-[arch] in any rpm package http://rpm.pbone.net/